# asp.net core defaultProxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

In net 4.5 we are working with proxy like this:

```
<system.net>
    <!-- -->
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://192.168.1.1:8888" bypassonlocal="True" autoDetect="False" />
        <module type="CommonLibrary.Proxy.MyProxy, CommonLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
    </defaultProxy>

    <settings>
        <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

but in asp.net core or test we can't found a solution like the above
Could someone please help me?

I really appreciate your help

Thanks, Regards

Answer (score 16):

You can set the proxy explicitly in the web.config as environment variables, as well as the domains it should skip. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Your.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="http_proxy" value="http://yourproxy.ins.local"/>
          <environmentVariable name="https_proxy" value="http://yourproxy.ins.local"/>
          <environmentVariable name="no_proxy" value=".local,.applicationinsights.azure.com,.applicationinsights.microsoft.com,.services.visualstudio.com"/>
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This works great! You can also set the environment variables server-wide by setting them globally on the server inside control panel.

Comment: This worked great in .net6

Comment: can i do the same for a proxy which requires user and password?

Comment: @Bouke Woudstra can i do the same for a proxy which requires user and password

Comment: Can anyone suggest me how to add same settings as above in net6.0 so that i could test in fiddler ?

Answer (score 9):

Whilst manually setting the proxy works when it's possible to use a `HttpClientHander`, defaulting all requests to do so without code, like you could do in the .NET Framework is currently not possible. Which is bummer if you're using a library that doesn't expose this functionality.

Thankfully, from .NET Core 3.0, this will be possible simply by setting environment variables (i.e. behaves exactly as Linux has worked forever): https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/37187

Alternatively, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/36553 added a new static `DefaultWebProxy` property on `HttpClient` that will allow you to accomplish the same thing via code. This will also be available in Core 3.0.

Comment: It is not working for me when I try to set the proxy for Fiddler url. I set the "http_proxy" environment variable with the value "http://127.0.0.1:8888". Fiddler is still not capturing the traffic for the dotnet core application.

Comment: I tried above solutions but still not working, I am trying to call interfax service but its not working successfully

Answer (score 8):

To use an HTTP proxy in .net core, you have to implement `IWebProxy` interface.This is from the `System.Net.Primitives.dll` assembly. You can add it to `project.json` if not already there

e.g.

```
"frameworks": {
    "dotnet4.5": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Net.Primitives": "4.3.0"
      }
    }
}
```

Implementation is very trivial

```
public class MyHttpProxy : IWebProxy
    {

        public MyHttpProxy()
        {
           //here you can load it from your custom config settings 
            this.ProxyUri = new Uri(proxyUri);
        }

        public Uri ProxyUri { get; set; }

        public ICredentials Credentials { get; set; }

        public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {
            return this.ProxyUri;
        }

        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
        {
            //you can proxy all requests or implement bypass urls based on config settings
            return false; 

        }
    }


var config = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseProxy = true,
    Proxy = new MyHttpProxy()
};

//then you can simply pass the config to HttpClient
var http = new HttpClient(config)
```

checkout https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebproxy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks yo much.
How i can do this for wcf client?

Comment: Hi.
I need use defaultProxy because i have a client wcf that i am accesing throught  a proxy with the ip address validated on the whitelist of my provider.

Comment: @MarceloOliveto are you using client-oriented WCF libraries in .net core ?   looks like it still does not support proxying,there is an issue opened for it https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1592

Comment: @MarceloOliveto Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a middleware. Did you have a look at this one:

https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy

there's a 'samples' folder:
https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/tree/dev/samples/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy.Samples

Other resources on the topic: 
http://josephwoodward.co.uk/2016/07/proxying-http-requests-asp-net-core-using-kestrel

http://overengineer.net/creating-a-simple-proxy-server-middleware-in-asp-net-core

Does a middleware works for you?

Comment: Hi.
I need use defaultProxy because i have a client wcf that i am accesing throught  a proxy with the ip address validated on the whitelist of my provider.

Comment: That's the wrong type of proxy. That makes your app a proxy, not make your app use a proxy.

Answer (score -4):

Another incompleted work around is:

After you deploy .NET Core app to a web server(mine is IIS). There is actually a web.config file in the root folder.

Manually add

```
 <system.net>
 <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
 </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
```

or your specific setting will do the magic

Only works on the server though. Your local build still won't work.

Comment: This doesn't work for later .net versions.