# Fiddler with WebAPI is acting flaky

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, proxy, asp.net-core, fiddler

We have an environment where we are using web-api with .NET CORE and since we can not host it in IIS, we are using fiddler to do a proxy. Now, I have a .NET client which calls this service.

However, the call to the service are very flaky, It can multiple calls back to back and then suddenly stops calling even though nothing changed between the calls. It is in real sense 'flaky'. Not sure what is causing it to behave in inconsistent manner.

I went through some articles and they suggested to have `ipv6.fiddler` or `localhost.fiddler` as my URl but nothing seems to be helping.

I also went ahead and updated my config file as mentioned [here](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp) in Telerik website. That also does not work

Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like something thinks it's under attack... does it always recover after a specific amount of time after the last call?

Comment: Hmmm.. That's interesting way to look at it. Actually I haven't tested it from that perspective but back to back calls fail after a time and first call in the morning or after a long time `mostly` works..I can do more testing before I give you a precise answer on this

Comment: Ok I restarted the machine and tried it. The first one did not hit the service but surprisingly second one did. And also 3-4 did not hit the break point. So I do not thing it is time/interval based.

Comment: have you tried using kestrel of web listener to see if the behaviour is from fiddler or from "your code"?

Comment: Well, I can try that but when service is called from the browser or from Test framework it never has that issue. Fiddler seems to be working fine there. BUT only when web client calls  it then there is this behavior shows up.

Comment: OK. This may come as way off as a solution. Turned out that it had nothing to do with Fiddler or calling application being webclient. It was because the method which prepares the call including the URL and args async and this method should had been awaited but its not so when it is called all the details a jumbled up.and sometimes the request is properly constructed and sometimes its not. Funny

Comment: strange; so is this some kind of serialisation bug? what you're saying shouldn't happen...

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding hooking to localhost may not always work.It has been the case for me as well .As the linked article states that

*allow the .NET Framework to automatically connect to Fiddler, start Fiddler before starting the .NET application* and also

There can be a number of things which can affect the localhost traffic,localhost traffic does not go through your default network interfaces or drivers so that it can correctly captured by network tools (I am referring to tools like wireshark or netmon etc) so it always little tricky to capture localhost traffic.If you want to use localhost in your urls,U have to make sure

1. Fiddler is started before the application starts so that fiddler can hook into the default proxy
2. In the application settings,try to rout the traffic through ipv4.fiddler
3. You can also write a custom proxy easily in .net core and enable it using config switch [using .net core proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637592/asp-net-core-defaultproxy/42641067#42641067)

Or an easy or **better way is to use machinename instead of the localhost**.This will make sure that if fiddler is started as listening as proxy , it will always capture the traffic .

```
e.g. http://localhost/api may or may not appear in fiddler but http://mymachine/api will always be captured.
```

Comment: Ok. I did restart my machine and started Fiddler as the first thing. After that I started my VS instances and changed the location from localhost to machinename. It did work for 5 or so calls and suddenly lost the connection. The funny thing is that this is the problem only with the .net Client not with the browser

Comment: if you really want to understand what is happening with the .net client and how it gets the proxy,you will have to take a system.net traces https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx .This will give you how It found the proxy and what proxy it is using.I am not sure if you are inside a corporate network, a domain policy rule can overwrite the proxy settings and can affect the default proxy used amd that might be one of the reason why you are loosing after 5 minutes into.Is it difficult to use a machinename instead of localhost?