# Is there any way to bypass a proxy when using QueueClient in the new .Net standard Azure API - Microsoft.Azure.Servicebus?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azureservicebus

I'm currently working on a .net core application that uses a azure service bus queue.

We are restricted to using AMQP over websockets and are behind a corporate proxy.

The QuietClient class does not provide anyway to set proxy information in any of it's constructors and we get a 
"Cannot connect to remote server" error when we attempt to write a message to the queue.

The exact same code works when I use it from home - not behind a proxy!

In regular .net bypassing a proxy could be achieved by adding to default proxy configuration in the web.config.

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://someAddredd:8888" />
    ......
</defaultProxy>
```

Because this is a .net core application the app doesn't use a web.config file for it's configuration.

When deployed to IiS a light weight web.Config file is created to allow the IIS to integrate with core's kestrel web server. However, adding the bypass proxy info to this does not work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net core defaultProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637592/asp-net-core-defaultproxy)

Comment: Hello Ted, I am facing the same issue. But even if i set the default proxy to autodetect on regular .net, i can't communicate to service bus. Can you please help!

Comment: Hi Palash. We were not able to resolve the issue (Bypassing the proxy with QueueClient). However, we got round the problem by writing to the service bus queue with the Azure restful Api's via HttpClient - Where you can add proxy information.